# serialization external library

Tags: java, serialization, redis

I am using `Redis` in one of our project.While I realized that redis needs objects to be serialized to be persisted, I want to understand how to deal with some classes which refers to external library classes`(StandardServletEnvironment)` in my case ,which doesn't implement `serializable` and we can't modify it as well ? I am getting `notSerializableException` in these cases.

Comment: Why would you keep a `StandardServletEnvironment` as an instance variable?

Comment: It is not actually an instance variable.The instance variable is ConfigurableEnvironment which I guess at runtime resolves to StandardServletEnvironment.

Comment: The question, though, is what reason there would be to persist this variable. If I understand correctly, it describes a live environment, one which will not necessarily be live when the object is deserialized.

Comment: Well, I am not sure as this is how the code was so far and the class itself implements Serializable with only this ConfigurableEnvironment as instance variables ,other variables are static.It's now when we has redis implemented I have started getting these runtime exceptions with serializations.I even tried skipping serialization for this field using transient but then it throws same error for some other thrird party library classes.

Comment: Why would it do that if this class has only one instance variable? Does it inherit from anything? Using `transient` would be the correct answer (if you have a different way of reconstructing the state when you deserialize), but you need to understand why the object is persisted at all, what you want to persist within it, etc. That is - focus your problem, understand your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store user defined Java objects in redis, serialization is the suitable option. However when you go with Java native serialization it comes with some drawbacks like you faced and also it is too slow. I also faced the same kind of problem, after a long search I came up with solution to use [kryo serialization](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo).Kryo doesn't needs serialization implementation and it is faster enough than java native serialization.

P.S:If you don't want to use kryo and use the java inbuilt serialization, then create serializable class and pass your object to this class and do your stuff.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer.Just want to understand,if I use Kryo,will it serialize the object which has a reference to some non-serializable third party classes.Also,would be great if you can provide a sample implementation.

Comment: yes, you can serialize the object which has a reference to some non-serializable third party classes. For implementation, refer [this](https://medium.com/@mykidong/howto-pool-kryo-instances-in-multithreaded-environment-97e34adf5f5e)

Answer (score 0):

As Praga stated, kyro is a good solution for (de)serialization of objects that do not implement Serializable interface. Here is a sample code for serialization with kyro, hope it helps:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();

private byte[] encode(Object obj) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream objStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Output objOutput = new Output(objStream);

    kryo.writeClassAndObject(objOutput, obj);

    objOutput.close();

    return objStream.toByteArray();

}

private <T> T decode(byte[] bytes) {
   return (T) kryo.readClassAndObject(new Input(bytes));
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Full Implementation for redis integration:

**RedisInterface** :

```
public class RedisInterface {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisInterface.class);

private static RedisInterface instance =null;

public static RedisInterface  getInstance ()
{
    if(instance ==null)
        createInstance();

    return instance ;
}

private static synchronized void createInstance()
{
    if(instance ==null)//in case of multi thread instances
        instance =new RedisInterface();
}

JedisConfig jedis = new JedisConfig();

public boolean setAttribute(String key, Object value)
{               
    return this.setAttribute(key, key, value);
}

public boolean setAttribute(String key, Object value, int expireSeconds)
{               
    return this.setAttribute(key, key, value, expireSeconds);
}

public boolean setAttribute(String key, String field, Object value)
{
    int expireSeconds = 20 *60; //20 minutes

    return this.setAttribute(key, field, value, expireSeconds);
}

public boolean setAttribute(String key, String field, Object value, int expireSeconds)
{
    try
    {               
        if(key==null || "".equals(key) || field==null || "".equals(field)) 
            return false;

        byte[]keyBytes = key.getBytes();
        byte[]fieldBytes = field.getBytes();
        byte []valueBytes = encode(value);          

        long start = new Date().getTime();

        jedis.set(keyBytes, fieldBytes, valueBytes, expireSeconds);

        long end = new Date().getTime();            
        long waitTime =end-start;


        logger.info("{} key saved to redis in {} milliseconds with timeout: {} seconds", new Object[] {key, waitTime, expireSeconds} );

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error( "error on saving object to redis. key: " + key, e);

        return false;
    }
}

public <T> T getAttribute(String key)
{
    return this.getAttribute(key, key);
}

public <T> T getAttribute(String key, String field)
{       
    try
    {       
        if(key==null || "".equals(key) || field==null || "".equals(field)) return null;

        byte[]keyBytes = key.getBytes();
        byte[]fieldBytes = field.getBytes();

        long start = new Date().getTime();

        byte[] valueBytes = jedis.get(keyBytes, fieldBytes);

        T o =null;
        if(valueBytes!=null && valueBytes.length>0)
            o = decode(valueBytes);     

        long end = new Date().getTime();

        long waitTime =end-start;

        logger.info("{} key read operation from redis in {} milliseconds. key found?: {}", new Object[] {key, waitTime, (o!=null)});

        return o;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error( "error on getting object from redis. key: "+ key, e);
        return null;
    }
}


Kryo kryo = new Kryo();

private byte[] encode(Object obj) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream objStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Output objOutput = new Output(objStream);

    kryo.writeClassAndObject(objOutput, obj);

    objOutput.close();

    return objStream.toByteArray();

}

private <T> T decode(byte[] bytes) {
   return (T) kryo.readClassAndObject(new Input(bytes));
}
```

}

**JedisConfig** :

```
public class JedisConfig implements Closeable
{   
private Pool<Jedis> jedisPool =  null;

private synchronized void initializePool()
{
    if(jedisPool!=null) return;

    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(Config.REDIS_MAX_ACTIVE_CONN)); // maximum active connections
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(Config.REDIS_MAX_IDLE_CONN));  // maximum idle connections
    poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(Long.parseLong(Config.REDIS_MAX_WAIT_MILLIS)); // max wait time for new connection (before throwing an exception)

    if("true".equals(Config.REDIS_SENTINEL_ACTIVE))
    {
        String [] sentinelsArray = Config.REDIS_SENTINEL_HOST_LIST.split(",");

        Set<String> sentinels = new HashSet();          
        for(String sentinel : sentinelsArray)
        {
            sentinels.add(sentinel);
        }

        String masterName = Config.REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME;

        jedisPool = new JedisSentinelPool(masterName, sentinels, poolConfig, Integer.parseInt(Config.REDIS_CONN_TIMEOUT));          
    }
    else
    {       
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, 
                Config.REDIS_IP, 
                Integer.parseInt(Config.REDIS_PORT),
                Integer.parseInt(Config.REDIS_CONN_TIMEOUT));
    }
}


protected Jedis getJedis()
{               
    if(jedisPool==null)
        initializePool();

      Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();

      return jedis;     
}   

public Long set(final byte[] key, final byte[] field, final byte[] value, int expireSeconds)
{
    Jedis redis = null; 
    Long ret =0L;

    try
    {
        redis = getJedis();

        ret = redis.hset(key, field, value);            
        redis.expire(key, expireSeconds);           
    }
    finally
    {
        if(redis!=null)         
            redis.close();
    }

    return ret;
}

public byte[] get(final byte[] key, final byte[] field) {

    Jedis redis = null ;
    byte[] valueBytes = null;

    try
    {
        redis = getJedis();

        valueBytes = redis.hget(key, field);
    }
    finally
    {       
        if(redis!=null)             
            redis.close();
    }

    return valueBytes;      
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {

    if(jedisPool!=null)     
        jedisPool.close();      
}
```

}

Comment: did not 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: java.util.LinkedHashMap